# Converting Current datetime to culture invariant

Tags: date, cultureinfo

I need to set an expiry date for my application (I know that it can be simply hacked, but that really isn't an issue or worry given the people who will be using it. I just need to expire yearly). I have code that seems to work, but I want to make sure it works with other culture settings. I tried playing with converting it to an invariant, but I got errors trying saying it cannot convert to date type. Here is what I have:

```
 Private Sub expcheck()
    Try
        Dim format As Date = #5/1/2013#
        Dim edate As Date = format.ToString()
        Dim daysleft As Integer = DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Now, edate)

        If Date.Now > edate Then
            MsgBox("This program was valid up to " & edate & " and will now close")
            Application.Exit()
        End If
        If daysleft < 30 Then
            MsgBox("This program expires on " & edate & vbNewLine & "You have " & daysleft & " Days left." & vbNewLine & "Export your work before expiry.")
        End If
    Catch e As Exception
        MsgBox(e.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

This seems to work, but I think it may screw up on other culture settings (i try changing my own settings/formats and it still works, but not sure why. Is this going to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may have answered my own question. It is not pretty, but by writing the date to a label with `datelabel.text = date.today.tostring("MM/dd/yyyy")`
 and then changing the code to:

```
Dim edate As DateTime = DateTime.Parse("05/01/2013", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
Dim nowdate As Date = Date.Parse(dateLabel.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
Dim daysleft As Integer = DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, nowdate, edate)
```

It works, but not pretty. Again, though, security is not an issue here, as there is only one client who would be using or need the software.

Comment: Actually, this is better, I think, and avoids the text label garbage. `Dim nowdate As Date = Format(Date.Today(), "MM/dd/yyyy")`